# Tasks package doesn't work

Tags: packages, tasks

I'm having problems with the `tasks` package.

Just with a very simple code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
hola
\end{document}
```

I get this log-file

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Unknown argument type 'b' for the command '\environment
(LaTeX3)        tasks'.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.771 \DeclareInstance
                       {tasks} {alphabetize} {default} { }
```

Comment: Update `xparse` package.

Comment: In fact, l3packages, but IT WORKS!!!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been resolved by updating [`l3packages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3packages).